# Codeigniter file not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using two installation for codeigniter one for frontend and one for admin panel. i am trying to upload file from admin panel to front end panel.

The structure is like this

```
abc.com
-root installtion for front end
-images
  -logos
-admin
  -another installation for admin panel
```

Now my code is this

```
$config = array(
            'upload_path'   => 'home/username/public_html/abc.com/images/logos/',
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|PNG',

            'file_name'     => $file_name,
            'max_width'     => '1024',
            'max_height'    => '768',
            'encrypt_name'  => true,
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
 $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            if(!$upload_data)
{
$this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
die();
}
```

but the file is not uploading and i m not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `$this->upload->do_upload()`

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

**EDIT 01**

Try this

```
$file_name = 'my_file';
$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => 'home/username/public_html/abc.com/images/logos/',
    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|PNG',
    'file_name'     => $file_name,
    'max_width'     => '1024',
    'max_height'    => '768',
    'encrypt_name'  => true,
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

Comment: now i getting an error
"You did not select a file to upload."

Comment: @opncart check now. you can use **EDIT 01**

Comment: i am using 
`$file_name=time()."-".$_FILES['logo']['name'];`
for file name
still getting file not selected error

Comment: check your from input

Comment: add name on here `$this->upload->do_upload(input field name)`